# Q. Is Kivy popup is displaying incorrect graphics because of GridLayout?

Tags: python-3.x, popup, kivy, grid-layout

On Raspberry with Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) I have Kivy setup the following way:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/pi/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-09-30_28.txt
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_gif (img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc1, git-Unknown, 20191231
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2(['window_egl_rpi'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <8192>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2(['text_pango'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Unpack subimage support is available
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

Regardless if I use the original 7" TFT display or a LCD (both on HDMI) sometimes randomly happens the popups come up in a see-through version or without colors, they do not cover the main screen. See the pictures below.

Some of my code to get an idea. Unfortunately I can not provide a bare minimum working sample.

```
# to avoid "segmentation error" due to raspbian version
os.environ["KIVY_WINDOW"] = "sdl2"

# uncommnent he two lines below when using the TFT display
from kivy.core.window import Window
#Window.fullscreen = 'auto'
#Window.show_cursor = False

# kivy modules first, if not Kivy may cause problems
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
from kivy.factory import Factory
kivy.require('2.0.0')

# main screen
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name="MAIN SCREEN"
        super(Screen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

# popup class  
class RequestBox(Popup):
    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        super(RequestBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.obj = obj

# main app class 
class Touch(App):
    pauseFlag = False           # init set pause to OFF  
        
    MainScreenTitle = "MainScreenTitle"
    MainScreenLabel = "MainScreenLabel"
    MessageBoxTitle = "MessageBoxTitle"
    MessageBoxLabel = "MessageBoxLabel"
    MessageButtonConfirm = "CONFERMA"
    MessageButtonCancel = "CANCELLA"
    MessageButtonEnter = "ENTRA"
    MessageButtonExit = "ESCI"

    def build(self):
                    sm = Builder.load_string("""
    
ScreenManager
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
    MainScreen:
        size_hint: 1, 1
        auto_dismiss: True
        # auto_dismiss: False   # original line
        title: app.MainScreenTitle       
        title_align: "center"
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "vertical"
            spacing: 10
            #Label:
                #text: app.MainScreenLabel
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .8
                Image:
                    orientation: "vertical"
                    center: self.parent.center
                    source: "ChemoMakerMark.jpg"
                    size_hint: 1, 1
            BoxLayout:
                orientation: "horizontal"
                spacing: 10
                size_hint: 1, .2
                # Button:   # uncomment to activate the nter button
                    # text: app.MessageButtonEnter  # start app
                    # on_press:
                        # #app.enter()
                Button:
                    font_size: 50
                    text: app.MessageButtonExit  # exit app
                    on_press:
                        self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                        app.exit()
                        
<MessageBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 0,204,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonConfirm  # "CONFIRM"
                on_press:
                    # self.disabled = True
                    self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                    app.do()
                    root.dismiss()
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.cancel()
                    root.dismiss()
                    
<ActivityBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            
<RequestBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 0,204,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonConfirm  # "CONFIRM"
                on_press:
                    self.disabled = True
                    self.background_color = 0,255,0,1
                    app.accept_request()
                    #root.dismiss()
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.reject_request()    # for testing the data flow when 400 is not desired
                    root.dismiss()
                    
<BarcodeBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.cancel_barcode()
                    root.dismiss()
                    
<RfidBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.cancel_rfid()
                    root.dismiss()
                    
<ErrorBox>:
    size_hint: 1, 1
    auto_dismiss: False
    title: app.MessageBoxTitle       
    title_align: "center"
    title_size: 30
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Label:
            font_size: '30sp'
            text: app.MessageBoxLabel
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            spacing: 10
            size_hint: 1, .5
            Button:
                font_size: 50
                background_color: 204,0,0,1
                text: app.MessageButtonCancel  # "CANCEL"
                on_press:
                    self.background_color = 255,0,0,1
                    app.annulla()
                    root.dismiss()
        """)

        return sm
```

What could be the problem?

**------ 1. UPDATE --------------------------------------------------**

The troubled popup is build and opens in the main thread. The problem remains in both cases: if the popup is run as a thread or directly.

```
def mainmethod():
    # setup the messages for the MessageBox popup
    self.messageTitle = "some title"
    self.messageLabel = "some message"
    # call popup2, the MessageBox popup
    self.popup2(self.messageTitle, self.messageLabel)

def popup2(self, boxTitle, boxLabel):   # popup for showing message
    #set the messages of the popup
    self.MessageButtonConfirm = "AVANTI"
    self.MessageButtonCancel = "CANCELLA"
    self.MessageBoxTitle = boxTitle
    self.MessageBoxLabel = boxLabel
    # set the popup structure
    self.popupMessage = MessageBox(self)

    # run the popup directly
    self.popupMessage.open()

    # run the popup in a thread
    # tp2 = threading.Thread(target = self.popupMessage.open)
    # tp2.start()
```

[image: scr3]

**------ 2. UPDATE --------------------------------------------------**

After retesting the code without applying any changes, the following error appeared. Any suggestions about the cause?

```
Exception in thread Thread-22:
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10, in <module>
     pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 923, in _build_canvas
     key, value, prule, idmap, True)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 247, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10:
 ...
       8:            texture: self.texture
       9:            size: self.texture_size
 >>   10:            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
      11:
      12:<-Button,-ToggleButton>:
 ...
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10, in <module>
     pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
 
 
 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
     self.run()
   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
     self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
   File "main.py", line 1490, in avanti
     self.step3()   # call the activity popup method
   File "main.py", line 1169, in step3
     self.popupActivity = ActivityBox(self)
   File "main.py", line 580, in __init__
     super(ActivityBox, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/modalview.py", line 186, in __init__
     super(ModalView, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/anchorlayout.py", line 68, in __init__
     super(AnchorLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
     super(Layout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 465, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 541, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 662, in _apply_rule
     child, crule, rootrule, rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 660, in _apply_rule
     root=rctx['ids']['root'], rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 465, in apply_class_lang_rules
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 541, in apply
     rule_children=rule_children)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 599, in _apply_rule
     rule.canvas_root, rootrule)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 929, in _build_canvas
     '{}: {}'.format(e.__class__.__name__, e), cause=tb)
 kivy.lang.builder.BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10:
 ...
       8:            texture: self.texture
       9:            size: self.texture_size
 >>   10:            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
      11:
      12:<-Button,-ToggleButton>:
 ...
 BuilderException: Parser: File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10:
 ...
       8:            texture: self.texture
       9:            size: self.texture_size
 >>   10:            pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
      11:
      12:<-Button,-ToggleButton>:
 ...
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'float'
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 242, in create_handler
     return eval(value, idmap), bound_list
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/data/style.kv", line 10, in <module>
     pos: int(self.center_x - self.texture_size[0] / 2.), int(self.center_y - self.texture_size[1] / 2.)
 
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 923, in _build_canvas
     key, value, prule, idmap, True)
   File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 247, in create_handler
     cause=tb)
```

**------ 3. UPDATE --------------------------------------------------**
Unfortunately by enabling the hardware video acceleration in `raspi-config` the issue is still present.

Before:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'VMware, Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'llvmpipe (LLVM 9.0.1, 128 bits)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.40'>
```

Now:

```
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 Mesa 19.3.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Broadcom'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'V3D 4.2'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
```

**------ 4th update --------------------------------------------------**
The graphical error seems to be related to a layout problem `[WARNING] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0xae191bf0> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.`

I checked the solutions below for the GridLayout but I can not see how they relate to my problem as I use FloatLayout. Any ideas?

1. [Kivy Gridlayout error: have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714133/kivy-gridlayout-error-have-no-cols-or-rows-set-layout-is-not-triggered)
2. [Kivy GridLayout Error : have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65505973/kivy-gridlayout-error-have-no-cols-or-rows-set-layout-is-not-triggered)

Comment: I'm tempted to guess this could be a graphics driver issue.

Comment: I realize this post could be perhaps in the Raspberry section of StackExchange.

Comment: @inclement I guess it could be the driver for the RPi4 graphic adapter

Comment: A fresh install of SDL2 and Cython by following these instructions https://kivy.org/doc/master/installation/installation-rpi.html did not help.

Comment: Make sure that the `Popup` is being built and opened on the main thread.

Comment: @JohnAnderson , this popup is opened in a thread in the main thread. I am not sure it opens and blocks the execution of the code otherwise.

Comment: Don't use a thread in the main thread, use the main thread.

Comment: @JohnAnderson, I followed your suggestion and run the popup directly in the main thread but it did not solve the problem. I later introduced time.sleep in between the popups and so far it works fine.

Comment: I have run the app for some time now and have not experienced further issues. I suspect however the problem is perhaps related to the GL reloading and window provider https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html.

Comment: According to the kivy docs https://kivy.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation/installation-rpi.html#installation-rpi the renderer is NOT hardware accelerated. I followed their instructions to add the user to the renderer group however kivy still does not recognize the GL. Could it be I use the incorrect environment `os.environ["KIVY_WINDOW"] = "sdl2"` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969990/kivy-does-not-detect-opengl-2-0?

Comment: The introduction of `time.sleep()` before popups does not help.

Comment: @JohnAnderson  I noticed the `[WARNING] <kivy.uix.gridlayout.GridLayout object at 0xae191bf0> have no cols or rows set, layout is not triggered.` always shows up together with the popup display error. I do not use GridLayout but FloatLayout.

Comment: What is `MessageBox`?

Comment: @JohnAnderson `<MessageBox>` is a popup just like `<RequestBox>` but with different button operations.